# Unable to open debug port: java.net.socketexception "Connection refused" - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, debugging, process, android-studio

This error occur while attaching debugger to process.

I've checked solutions from similar issue with `"Socket closed"` and it does not fix this.

After this runnig app with debugger attached returns:

```
Error running Android Debugger (port): Unable to open debugger port : java.net.SocketException "Connection reset"
```

Any ideas ?

```
Env:
Android Studio v1+
Linux x64
```

Comment: See if this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23639043/3168859) helps you..do tell me if any problems..

Answer (score -1):

Check your firewall settings, open this port
Close any other tools or windows that may be connecting to the device, i.e. chrome inspect window, another eclipse, etc..