# Unable to open debugger port > (127.0.0.1:49723): java.net.SocketException "socket closed"

Tags: android-studio, debugging, android-emulator

After some update of my AndroidStudio IDE, I can no longer launch my application in the emulator. I get the following error:

> Error running Android [build]: Unable to open debugger port
>   (127.0.0.1:49723): java.net.SocketException "socket closed"

My Android emulator is running on the background, but IDE just does not find its way to the emulator.

Any ideas, please ?

**Edit:**
I found several possible options to fix the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615523/unable-to-open-debugger-port-java-net-socketexception-socket-closed).
The tip posted by Eric Lin helped me too. (Switching to Native debug type.)
But I do not develop with C++ for Android. Only Java currently.
Therefore, this solution is IMHO very uncommon. Moreover, I have no idea why this problem suddenly appeared (after A.S. update) and what would be the ordinary and propper solution...